# Как сгенерировать SOAP-сообщение с XOP (XML-binary Optimized Packaging)?

Tags: java, mime, soap

Как программно сгенерировать SOAP-сообщение с XOP (XML-binary Optimized Packaging)?
Должно получится следующее:

```
--uuid:8423cef3-2e42-4e33-82a6-4e970071fad0
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns2:EccMessage xmlns="ess.org" xmlns:ns2="http://gate.ecc.org/eccMessages"><ns2:data><xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:228af799-cc11-4cd2-b871-a2fe599c79d8-1@gate.ecc.org"/></ns2:data></ns2:EccMessage></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
--uuid:8423cef3-2e42-4e33-82a6-4e970071fad0
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <228af799-cc11-4cd2-b871-a2fe599c79d8-1@gate.ecc.org>

zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
--uuid:8423cef3-2e42-4e33-82a6-4e970071fad0--
```

Comment: код бы отформатировали, а то заходишь в вопрос, видишь биллибирду и выходишь

Comment: Хотел отформатировать, не могу зайти в режим редактирования.